# How can I get just the Count result?

Tags: json, node.js, connection

I have this node `msnodesqlv8` connection and I am counting the number of records from one table. I am getting the result as `{ total: 26 }` and the expected result should be 26. Here is my code:

```
 pool.connect().then(() => {         
    pool.request().query('SELECT count([TaskID]) as total FROM [db_test].[dbo].[tb_test]', (err, result) => {    
      myResults = result.recordset[0];
      console.log(myResults);
      })
  });
```

Comment: myResults.total

Comment: It works, can you please write in form of an answer so I can put as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are getting data in object form. now you have to access the object from the result.

```
pool.connect().then(() => {         
    pool.request().query('SELECT count([TaskID]) as total FROM [db_test].[dbo].[tb_test]', (err, result) => {    
      myResults = result.recordset[0].total;
      console.log(myResults.total); // it should provides you expected result
      })
  });
```